# Why don't CSS3 animations work on outline with default none?

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-animations, outline

I've got to this point in which I'm trying to do a hilite animation on an element which I can't move or modify its boundings, so i used an outline in addition to its background color to have an animation area bigger than the element itself (here's a sample):

```css
@keyframes hilite {
    0% {
        background-color: transparent;
        outline: #ffffff solid 10px;
    }
    20% {
        background-color: #F6F6BC;
        outline: #F6F6BC solid 10px;
    }
    100% {
        background-color: transparent;
        outline: #ffffff solid 10px;
    }
}
```

But now i'm freaking seeing that the background animation triggers in every case, but the outline animation works only when the element has an outline style value (none doesn't work, when background none doesn't avoid animations).

You can see it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jKnbn/1/).

I don't want to fix it, it's already fixed, but understand it - seems illogical to me.

Lots of thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Border and outline styles cannot be animated; this is [by design](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#animatable-css). When you attempt to animate a change from `none` to `solid`, as shown in the last box in your fiddle, what happens is that it switches to `solid` *immediately*, which causes it to display as a black outline momentarily before animating to the color that's defined, so it doesn't actually *animate* from no outline to a solid outline in that sense.

If you need a smooth animation from an invisible outline to a visible outline, animate `outline-color` between a color value and `transparent` instead of `outline-style` between `solid` and `none`. I see that you're using `#ffffff` in place of `transparent`, which also works provided the background of the container is also white.

Comment: Hmmm... maybe I'm not understanding what you are saying, but I think this doesn't solve my doubt.
I would be disposed to accept that uotline can't be animated from none to any value. But my tries doesn't show that.
If I **statically set** the outline to none, then I **try to animate it from** none, to some value, then to none, then to some value, etc, the animation never happens.
But if i **statically set** it to some value, then I **try to animate it from** some value, to none, then to some value, then to none, etc, the animation **does happen**, which demonstrates the animation is possible.

Comment: `outline-style` can't be animated; what you're seeing is an **immediate change**, not a gradual transformation, while `outline-color` *does* change gradually.

Comment: Oh, stupid me, I see now. You'd explained it perfectly but I didn't notice the style property emphasis. Lots of thanks.

Comment: By the way, AFAIK, transparent is not a valid value for outline-color and border color, am I right? Should we update the answer?

Comment: It *is* a valid value for both properties.

Comment: You're right @BoltClock, I don't know why my IDE (PHPStorm) complies about it, I'll report the issue. Lost of thanks.