# CSS Transition border reverting instantaneously

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

Why does the border disappear instantaneously and not slowly like the other properties?

Note: in ie the border appears instantaneously instead of the 2 second delay.

```css
.figure {
 height: 160px;
 width: 160px;
 background-color: red;
 transition-property: all;
 transition-duration: 2s;
}

.figure:hover{
 background-color: blue;
 border: 10px solid pink;
 color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class='figure'>Stackoverflow</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [initial value of the `border-style` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-style) is `none`.

This means that the border doesn't transition back because the border isn't suppose to be displayed at all when `border-style` is set to `none`. If you set the initial `border-style` property value to something like `solid`, then it will transition as expected.

It's also worth pointing out that the default [`border-width` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-width) value is `medium` and and the default [`border-color` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-color) value is [`currentColor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color) (which essentially means it will be whatever the `color` property is set to).

```css
.figure {
  height: 160px;
  width: 160px;
  background-color: red;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0;
  transition-property: all;
  transition-duration: 2s;
}
.figure:hover {
  background-color: blue;
  border: 10px solid pink;
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class='figure'>Stackoverflow</div>
```

Comment: Ha! well that makes sense! Thanks!

Comment: The more accurate explanation is that border styles cannot be transitioned at all. You cannot even transition between solid and dashed. And certainly transitioning to or from any of the 3d-looking border styles would be a challenge to make look good, let alone standardize.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14385422/why-dont-css3-animations-work-on-outline-with-default-none/14386672#14386672, where the same thing applies to outline styles.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the transition property in both the `class` and the `class:hover`

```
.figure {
    height: 160px;
    width: 160px;
    background-color: red;
    transition: all linear 2s;
    -webkit-transition: all linear 2s;
    -moz-transition: all linear 2s;
}

.figure:hover{
    background-color: blue;
    border: 10px solid pink;
    color: yellow;
    transition: all linear 2s;
    -webkit-transition: all linear 2s;
    -moz-transition: all linear 2s;
}
```

Adding the `transition` to both the `class` and its `:hover` makes the `div` revert to its normal state at the same time it changes on `hover`